# "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" ERROR

Tags: python

For some reason, I keep getting this error from AWS Lambda:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "list indices must be integers or slices, not str",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/python.py\", line 25, in lambda_handler\n    metricName = event['detail']['configuration']['metrics']['metricStat']['metric']['name']\n"
  ]
}
```

The following part is the JSON part for what I am trying to reference to:

```
"configuration": {
      "metrics": [
        {
          "id": "ajdhflksdf4",
          "metricStat": {
            "metric": {
              "namespace": "AWS/RDS",
              "name": "CPUUtilization",
              "dimensions": {
                "DBInstanceIdentifier": "123456-rds-tester"
              }
            },
            "period": 60,
            "stat": "Average"
          },`
          "returnData": "True"
        }
      ],
      "description": "This metric monitors rds cpu utilization"
    }
```

I want to reference the name in the metric part and all of that is under the key 'detail'. I was expecting to receive "CPUUtilization" for metricName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value associated with the key `metrics` is a list. You should access `...['metrics'][0]['metricStat']...` instead of `...['metrics']['metricStat']...`, as the sub-dictionary you wish to access is stored in the 0th index of the list.

Comment: That worked, but can you help me with one last question pls?
What is this error message? I received it for another part, but it was not a list of anything. It was just a normal dictionary?
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Sounds you like you are trying to index a string by accident. Indices of a string must be integers - you may be experiencing a situation where a value is just a string and you are trying to index it like it is a key/value pair. @JohnKennedy